# Codeigniter, how to reuse function from Model

Tags: codeigniter

I'm still learning MVC approach and I have a question regarding on the proper usage.

How can I convert the function below so that I can reuse it:

old situation (every time I call this function, I can specify a different table name):

```
foreach ($client_data->fetch_all("gender") as $aRow):
```

new situation in codeigniter:

function View:

```
<?php foreach($fetch_all->result() as $o) : ?>
```

function Controller:

```
    public function load_client_data() {
    $client_id = $_POST['id'];

    $client_data = $this->user_model->get_client_data($client_id);
    $fetch_all = $this->user_model->fetch_all();

    $this->template->loadAjax("clients/client_data.php", array(
        "client_data" => $client_data,
        "fetch_all" => $fetch_all)
    );
```

function Model:

```
    public function fetch_all() {
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

code in the new situation works fine but how can I pass the table name so that I can reuse fetch_all function as in the old situation.

I have a form with 20 select options, now I have to create 20 different functions for each select options to retrieve the data instead of calling one function with only another table name. I have tried different options but not my desired result. How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to make a base_model in `application/core` folder.
- In that `base_model`, you need to define all generic functions like fetch_all, get_one, get_based_on_id etc
- In each model, you need to 2 two things, inherit from base_model and set a parameter named `tablename` or what else suits you in which you set exact table name for which you are defining model
- Now in controller, you will load model and call base_model's function for example you loaded `User` model and you will call like `$this->User->fetch_all()`
- Al thought `fetch_all` is defined in base_model and it will work

Let me know if you need more info.